# Setting the filename for an Excel file in the SaveAs window without sendkeys in vba

Tags: vba, ms-office

I would like to know if the SaveAs window filename textbox has a property that I could set text to.  Currently I'm using the sendkeys function, which works fine for most things until I run into the special characters like parentheses.

My current code is basically:

```
SaveFldr = "S:\Desktop\grape
Filename = "Grape Data"
Application.SendKeys "{F12}"  ' opens the save as window
Application.SendKeys SaveFldr & Filename & ".pdf"
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}"
```

Basically I'm looking for a way to set the filename without the sendkeys function.  Such as..

```
Filename.Textbox = Filename
```

** Assuming the textbox within the SaveAs window was named that.

Comment: And before its mentioned. No I cannot use the Application.Sendkeys "{(}" to make the parentheses as they are saved within the name and that needs to stay that way.

Comment: What application are you running this from?

Comment: Microsoft Excel

Comment: Why not use `Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`?

Comment: Technically I'm using the print to pdf within the print menu, which in turn opens the save as window.

Comment: Yeah but if the end goal is to create a PDF, it seems like you're coming at it a roundabout way? `SendKeys` is, as this demonstrates, pretty unreliable.

Comment: I've now found out how unreliable it can be and regret using it.  But I have quite an extensive page of code dedicated to using it now and was hoping that I could keep that while being able to fix this small issue with the save as window.  The Filename in the SaveAs window is the only thing I'm looking for (basically the textbox name property)

Comment: That's like duct-taping the rearview mirror on a totaled car... highly suggest the proper alternative.

Comment: Maybe someday I'll go back through and rewrite this; but today is not that day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use code like the following one

```
Sub CallSaveAs()
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant
    Dim SaveFldr  As String
    Dim fileName As String

    SaveFldr = "S:\Desktop\grape"
    fileName = "Grape Data"

    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        fileFilter:="PDF Files (*.PDF), *.pdf", _
        InitialFileName:=SaveFldr & Application.PathSeparator & fileName)

    If Not TypeName(fileSaveName) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "Save as " & fileSaveName
        ' Save the sheetas PDF
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileName
    End If

End Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Really all OP needs is the `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileName`.... but as you saw in the comments, it was hard time trying to say that.

Comment: Ah,I thought he wanted to select the filename and wanted to filll the `SaveAs` dialogbox with an inital filename

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know if I can get it to work

Comment: But you see that the filename and folder is hard-coded, so I just assumed that just the save as PDF was needed, in any case, +1 for putting it together.

Comment: Yes, but as said, I thought that's the initial filename OP wants to display in the `SaveAs` dialogbox

Comment: I did get this to work with the ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=Filename.  Thank you @BigBen.  Not sure if I check this as the answer though

Comment: Eh, give Storax the credit, it's all good. All that matters is that the question is resolved. Maybe today is the day this gets rewritten, and we're all happy for that :-)

Comment: `fileSaveName <> False` will throw a Type Mismatch, right?

Comment: Fixed, but look at the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getsaveasfilename) :-)

Comment: To Microsoft's credit, the docs don't show the declarations, but presumably `fileSaveName` is a `Variant`, not a `String` (which is partially how you fixed it anyway).